# AspnetCore Web Application with SignalR running on multiple replicas in Docker Swarm cannot connect to Redis Server

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

My application, built using .NET Core 6, is deployed on a Docker Swarm with multiple replicas distributed across different nodes. The application utilizes SignalR messaging for real-time communication, and Redis is employed for managing session data.

When the application runs on a single replica, the connectivity to Redis works without any issues. However, when the application is scaled to multiple replicas, the connectivity to Redis becomes sporadic and unpredictable. I'm unable to determine the source of this problem, and it is causing inconsistency in the application's behavior.

To better understand the issue, I created a simple application to simulate the same scenario. The code for this application is as follows:

Program.cs File

```
using WebSocketApp.Hubs;

namespace WebSocketApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
               {
                   options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
               })
               .AddStackExchangeRedis("10.128.116.21:4009,password=1234", options =>
               {
                   options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "WebSoketTest";
                   options.Configuration.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
               });
          
            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseWebSockets();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub"); // Map SignalR hub
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });

            app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

File ChatHub.cs

```
namespace WebSocketApp.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
}
```

File index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="messageInput" />
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="chatBox"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/5.0.0/signalr.js"></script>
    <script>
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/chatHub")
            .build();

        // Log incoming messages from the server
        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
            console.log("Received message from server:", message);
            const chatBox = document.getElementById("chatBox");
            const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
            messageDiv.textContent = message;
            chatBox.appendChild(messageDiv);
        });

        async function sendMessage() {
            const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInput");
            const message = messageInput.value;

            if (message.trim() !== "") {
                // Log outgoing messages to the server
                console.log("Sending message to server:", message);
                await connection.invoke("SendMessage", message);
                messageInput.value = "";
            }
        }

        connection.start()
            .then(() => console.log("WebSocket connection established"))
            .catch(console.error);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

On one replica conection OK, on multiple conteiners not working.

I have checked all the networks for possible leaks or problems, but I haven't found any issues. I also tested with different versions of .NET Core, but the same result persists.

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the [ChannelPrefix](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7814#issuecomment-431103793) so that multiple applications can share one Redis server.

Like below, change

```
 options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "WebSoketTest";
```

to

```
 options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "WebSoketTest"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```